# what are the conditions when $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$

Tags: number-theory

what are the conditions when $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$? I know that it is divisible by $a+b $ when $n $ is odd but I want to find out when it is divisible by $a-b$ and when it is not.

Comment: For fixed $a,b$ or all $a,b$?

Comment: when $2b^n \equiv 0 \pmod{a-b}$, e.g. $a=2b$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is taken from an on going programming competition, https://www.codechef.com/AUG18B/problems/GCDMOD

Comment: In addition to voting to close this as off-topic, I have flagged it for moderator review, as per the [contest problem guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy/16775#16775).